Another Conditionally open global p:confirmDialog with p:confirm
​I have a dialog which is shown by PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic(). In this dialog are some input fields and two buttons. One to apply any changes and one to cancel. Before the changes should be applied, I want to show a confirmation message. But only when the input fields have some certain values.
<p:form>
  <p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel for="input1" value="Input 1">
    <p:inputText id="input1" value="#{bean.input1}">
    <p:outputLabel for="input2" value="Input 2">
    <p:inputText id="input2" value="#{bean.input2}">
  </p:panelGrid>
  <p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:commandButton id="apply" action="#{bean.apply}">
      <p:confirm header="Confirmation" 
                 message="Do you really want to apply the values?" 
                 beforeShow="beforeShow();"
                 disabled="#{not bean.showConfirm()}">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton id="cancel" action="#{bean.cancel}">
​  </p:panelGrid>
</p:form>

​The problem now is that #{bean.showConfirm()} for disabled is evaluated when the dialog is shown. But I need disabled to be evaluated when the apply button is pressed.
I also tried using beforeShow which is documented as: Callback to execute before displaying confirmation dialog. Return false to prevent dialog from appearing.
function beforeShow(){
    alert('*** beforeShowFalse ***');
    return false;
}

But whatever beforeShow() returns, the confirm dialog is always shown.
Any hints welcome!
I am using PF 12.0.4 and JSF 2.3.

I solved it without the global p:confirm by checking in the apply() method whether a confirm message should be shown.
